# Filter fcurves using script

Tags: python, fcurves

I have an object with more than 100 fcurves. In my addon, the user has an option to filter these fcurves, and show only those that their max value is above a certain threshold. I'm using fcurve.hide and fcurve.select for this. The problem, is that indeed it filter the graph, but not the fcurves list, as can be seen in this screenshot:
[image]
How can I filter those fcurves also from the list, something like the DopSheet.filter_fcurve_name option (the filter box underneath the graph)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can move them into a Channel group to get them out of the way, but you can not hide the overview of the channels.

The user can do this by marking the channels with SHIFT and pressing CTRL+G[image: ChannelGroup]

And with coding:

```
group = bpy.data.actions['CubeAction'].groups.new("hidden")
bpy.data.actions['CubeAction'].fcurves[0].group=group
```